# Есть ли практическая польза в криптовалютах?

Tags: криптовалюта

Криповалюта выполняет туже функции что и обычная валюта, но потребляет огромное количество энергии.
Согласно исследованию, на майнинг 1$ в Bitcoin тратится в три раза больше электроэнергии, чем на 1$ в золоте и других драгоценных металлах. В промежутке между 1 января 2016 года и 30 июня 2018 года исследователи установили, что на майнинг 1$ в биткоинах тратится порядка 17 МДж и в среднем 7-14 МДж на майнинг других известных видов криптовалюты, включая Ethereum, Litecoin и Monero. В то же время расход на добычу драгоценных и редкоземельных металлов составил 6-9 МДж. Больше энергии, чем майнинг криптовалют, занимает только производство алюминия (110 МДж).

«Сравнение показателей указывает на то, что майнинг криптовалюты потребляет больше энергии, чем добыча полезных ископаемых эквивалентной стоимости», – пишут исследователи.

Кроме того, исследователи заявили, что анализ учитывал энергозатраты, необходимые для охлаждения оборудования, используемого в криптомайнинге, а также расходы на техническое обслуживание и инфраструктуру.

Cсылка на статью: https://fomag.ru/news/na-mayning-bitkoina-tratitsya-v-tri-raza-bolshe-energii-chem-na-dobychu-zolota-issledovanie/

Не рационально ли будет запретить любой майнинг?

Comment: Есть страны, где электричество дешёвое или даже бесплатное. Зачем запрещать, если майнящий электричество всё равно оплачивает? Ну и всё равно не получится запретить.

Comment: Может вам вообще электрическое освещение запретить? Сидите с лучиной, когда стемнеет

Comment: Нужно закрыть, потому что оффтоп.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу смысла в запрете майнинга. Он выгоден для поставщиков электроэнергии. Я согласен с вами и считаю, что криптовалюты (Bitcoin, Ethereum, Litecoin и все остальные) - бесполезны. Их невозможно подделать, но практической пользы от них нет. Да, ими можно расплатится в отдельных интернет-магазинах, но не легче ли расплатится обычными деньгами? 
По-моему вопрос не по теме. На данном сайте задают вопросы насчет программирования и системного администрирования. Если я не ошибаюсь, раздела про майнинг нет.

Comment: Идея криптовалюты в том, что количество коинов принципиально ограничено, следовательно она не инфляционна.